# excel - conditionally adding values and outputting a list without blanks

Tags: excel, array-formulas

**Overview:**

Col-A = has bunch of values

Col-B = has the desired values

Col-C = a list of all the desired values

```
Col-A Col-B Col-C
V1    x     V1
V2          V2
V3    x     V5
V4
V5    x
```

**Desired:**

Display Col-C values through a formula

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use a helper column to avoid array formulas. In **D2** enter:

```
=IF(B2="x",1+MAX($D$1:D1),"")
```

and copy down.  Then in **C2** enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),D:D,0)),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

In **C2** place the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$9,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$9<>"",ROW($B$2:$B$9)),ROW(1:1))),"")
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: thanks. why would you want to avoid using the array data structure? Wouldn't the array be cleaner?

Comment: @Lacer  For big worksheets, array formulas can really slow down calculation.

Comment: thanks a lot for the example could you also do an array version of this as well? so I know how to do that too??  thanks again..

Comment: @Lacer  See my **EDIT#1:**